# Hedging and measuring repo rate risk

Tags: hedging, greeks

How is repo rate risk hedged? And is repo rate dv01 the usual greek for this?

i am talking about repo risk in a derivative on a bond

Comment: I assume you are talking about overnight repo (not term repo); you could hedge it with OIS swaps.

Comment: well the forward bond price depends on term repo...  and i think term repo may easily have a low correlation with o/n repo...

Comment: and i think that ois can be a fair first guess of repo, but, i am sure it can easily move quite differently

Comment: It seemed to me if you have locked in a term repo then you are fully financed until completion of the deal and have no interest rate risk.

Comment: @noob2 yes i agree , you do a term repo to hedge the forward price (and implied repo rate).  after all a repo deal is a forward minus spot.

Answer (score 1):

Repo risk is not always perfectly linked to OIS rates, although highly correlated.
Therefore in large markets (say US) get a different repo curve as GC-OIS spread risk is material.
This has led to repo rate futures: http://www.marketswiki.com/wiki/GCF_Repo_Index_futures
http://www.dtcc.com/charts/dtcc-gcf-repo-index
Would also note that repo rates from Tresury/MBS/Agency will differ and therefore have different contracts and risk buckets.